# Excel VBA find multiple values in one cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have some code to search for a value in a cell and then do something if that value is found. My text step is to search for two values in one cell. If the two values are found do something.

This is my code for searching for 1 value;

```
Dim C As Range
Set SrchRng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
Do
    Set C = SrchRng.Find("Wash", LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not C Is Nothing Then C.EntireRow.Delete
    Loop While Not C Is Nothing
```

My question is how can I adapt this to look for two words instead of one?

For example cells may contain

"The cat sat on the matt"

I need to find cells with the word cat and matt.
I have spent a long time looking online for how do do this but nothing I find seems to help.

Thanks in advance!

I

Comment: I believe if you add the argument to `Find`, `LookAt:=xlPart` then you can find either or both "matt" and "cat" in the cell.

Comment: Can you elaborate please Matt, I am not familiar with LookAt:=xlPart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could loop over the range and examine each cell:

```
Sub FindBoth()
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        v = r.Value
        If InStr(v, "cat") > 0 And InStr(v, "matt") > 0 Then
            r.EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

---

```
Dim r As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim x As Long
Dim y As Long

i = 1
x = 1
y = 1

For Each r In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    v = r.Value
    If InStr(v, "ION") > 0 And InStr(v, "Dog") > 0 Then

        r.EntireRow.Cut
        Debug.Print (r.Value)

        Union(Cells(i, 7), Cells(x, 8), Cells(y, 9)).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        i = i + 1
        x = x + 1
        y = y + 1




    End If
Next r
```

Comment: Perfect Gary! Thanks a lot, i presume to do something different to delete the entire row i can do r.EntireRow.Offset or something else?

Comment: I have tried to alter this code so that if it finds the values it will cut and paste the entire row somewhere else. However i get an error saying my destination range doesn't match. The entire row is 3 columns, and i have used union to select 3 cells to paste to. I cant understand why this does not work @Gary